# Booting after battery change

Tags: 16.04

At "intramfs" what command to boot "fsck" to clear booting fault ?
I have changed the computer battery and the boot process stops at a fault which ends with the prompt "initranfs".
It says; 
/dev/sda1 ; UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY
fsck ended with status code 4.

Can you tell me what to type from here, please ?
John Scott.

Answer (score 0):

Type `fsck /dev/sda1` at the prompt and answer yes to all questions .. or `fsck -y /dev/sda1` if you want to answer yes automatically - It can be quite a large number of prompts to answer. After that, reboot.

Comment: I have now had  2 problems solved and am very happy. Thank you.